# Trying to create a log in page

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, authentication

I am trying to create a login page where you would enter in a username and a password. It will query the database for the information you typed in, and if it is in the database, it will log me into the program. If not, it will display a message saying information is not correct.

Here is what I have so far.

```
private void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        SqlConnection UGIcon = new SqlConnection();
        UGIcon.ConnectionString = "XXXXXXXXX; Database=XXXXXXXX; User Id=XXXXXXX; password=XXXXXXXXX";
        UGIcon.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT User(Username, '') AS Username, User(Password,'') AS Password, FROM User WHERE Username='"
            + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Password + "'", UGIcon);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string userText = txtUsername.Text;
        string passText = txtPassword.Password;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (this.userText(dr["stUsername"].ToString(), userText) &&
                this.passText(dr["stPassword"].ToString(), passText))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

        }

        dr.Close();

        UGIcon.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But, the only problem is it does not work at all. I am not sure I have the correct statements to query the database either. I am also getting an error on the "this.userText" As well.

```
{  
    if (this.userText(dr["stUsername"].ToString(), userText) &&   
        this.passText(dr["stPassword"].ToString(), passText))
    {
```

For the error I'm getting, it tells me the WPF does not contain a definition for it

I am a little unsure of how to fix it and go about it as this is the first time I've had to do this. But I think I have a decent start to it though.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it's "not working"?  When you step through it in a debugger, where does it go wrong?  Also, please note that storing user passwords in plain text is a *famously* bad idea.  The original text of a password should never be readable.  Instead, store it as a 1-way hashed value.  Then when a user logs in, hash the provided password and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with this structure:

```
this.userText(dr["stUsername"].ToString(), userText)
```

First, `userText` isn't a function, it's a local variable.  So I'm not sure what you're even *trying* to do by invoking it as a function.  Are you just trying to compare the variable?  Something like this?:

```
this.userText.Equals(dr["stUsername"].ToString())
```

Second, the error is telling you that the object doesn't contain a definition for `userText` because, well, it doesn't.  When you do this:

```
this.userText
```

you're specifically looking for a *class-level* member called `userText` on the object itself.  But your variable is local to the function:

```
string userText = txtUsername.Text;
```

So just drop the `this` reference:

```
userText.Equals(dr["stUsername"].ToString())
```

Third, the column reference is incorrect.  Note how you define the columns in your SQL query:

```
SELECT User(Username, '') AS Username, User(Password,'') AS Password ...
```

The column is called `Username`, not `stUsername`:

```
userText.Equals(dr["Username"].ToString())
```

**Edit:**  @Blam made a good point in a comment, which demonstrates a logical error in the code.  If no results are returned from your query, the `while` loop will never execute.  So no message will be shown.  You can check for results with something like `HasRows`:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
```

This kind of renders the previous things moot, of course.  But it's still good to know what the problems were and how to correct them, so I'll leave the answer whole for the sake of completeness regarding the overall question.

---

A few other notes which are ***important*** but not immediately related to your question...

1. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  You'll want to look into using parameterized queries instead of concatenating string values like that.  Essentially what this code does is treat user input as *executable code* on the database, allowing users to write their own code for your application.
2. Please don't store user passwords in plain text.  The importance of this can not be overstated.  The original text of a password should never be readable from storage.  Instead, store a hash of the password.  There's [*a lot* more to read](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on the subject.
3. Look into [`using` blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose of resources when you're done with them.

Comment: This is for a school project. We basically just have to show that we can pull data from a database, so we aren't too concerned about security at the moment.

Otherwise I would be very concerned about security

Comment: @Travis: School projects are a *great* opportunity to demonstrate one's abilities in a low-pressure environment.  Don't underestimate the value of producing better results than your peers :)

Comment: If it returns a row this will always be true userText.Equals(dr["stUsername"].ToString()) as it is a where condition.

Comment: @Travis: I found another error in the code and have updated my answer accordingly.  The column reference being used to pull data from the `dr` object was incorrect.

Comment: @Blam: Good point.  If any rows are found at all then no conditional is needed.

Comment: @Travis: I've updated the answer to include Blam's point as well.  Turns out there were several things wrong with the code :)

Comment: Why have the overhead of rdr when it is not required. You incorporated my answer. Did you you down vote my answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*)  FROM User WHERE Username='"
    + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Password + "'", UGIcon);

Int32 rowsRet = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if(rowsRet > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

You still have exposure to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer what problem this code fixes?

Comment: @David Could you elaborate what it does not fix?  Did you test this?  Did you vote it down?

Comment: @David Buy a vowel.  It fixes that syntax error because it does not need that statement.  If that Username and Password is in the table the count will be > 0.  If not the count will be zero.  That is all you need to validate a Username and Password.

Comment: @David At least when they copy paste it works.  Your answer did not even work until you copied mine.

Comment: Oh, you didn't 'copy' exactly you used a less efficient syntax of HasRows. It is a logic error that is not present in my answer that you did not pick up on until I spelled it out to you.  If you cannot tell what that code does from inspection then that is your problem.  select count(*) where a and b is one of the most basic statements.  Column names are UserName and Passworde.  Really I need to explain that sql will return a count of rows where username = xtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Password.